# I2C Master-Slave Arduino system to control array of steppers

Tags: arduino-mega, stepper

trying to make a system where one master Arduino makes moving 9 steppers 28BYJ-48 by 3 stepper on each slave arduino.

While all the parts on their way to me, wonder to check with professionals.

Maybe I've missed something?

Any suggestions and tips are welcome.
Thank you.

[image: Sketch]
[image: Scheme]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I think your schematic might be wrong there. Only one MEGA is connected to a positive side of a battery.

The MEGA can only run on 7V to 12V. *BUT PLEASE DO NOT apply the voltage to the `3V3` or `5V` pin.*

```
Microcontroller ATmega1280
Operating Voltage   5V
Input Voltage (recommended) 7-12V
Input Voltage (limits)  6-20V
```

And also, I would only put in another MEGA when you don't have enough I/O pins.

```
Digital I/O Pins    54 (of which 15 provide PWM output)
```

In theory you could use 13 steppers on one MEGA. Try slowly scaling up.
You don't need PWM for steppers, maybe you're confused with servo's?

And why not use one of the stepper-driving MEGA's as the master? (In the first picture, slave 1 isn't even connected to the SDA/SCL lines of the I2C bus.

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand the problem. A
 arduino mega would have no problem controlling 9 of these steppers alone. If you are asking about i2c protocol please be more specific about what you need help with.

Comment: How much does she more can handle? Can you point me, how it possible, because as my newbie brain think when one stepper requires 4 PWM outputs and mega has only 15, I can drive only 3. Thank you for your help!

Comment: These steppers doesn't require any timers really, you can control them with 4 outputs each and control each stepper in code.

Comment: Well, 4 pwm outputs, 15 ppm on each arduino.

Comment: Why would you need PWM? It's not like doing micro-stepping on a 28BYJ-48 is useful?

Comment: If you were to tell us what this system of yours is going to do, we might be of more help.

Comment: It is for simultaneously moving steppers, like in kinetic statues. With accelerated moves and so on.

Comment: Well first off, if two or more steppers need to go simultaneously just connect them in parallell. These stepper doesent require any PWM or timers really, in normal program loop you need to delay stepping them or else it will stall them(run faster than they can handle), so maybe by using a non-blocking code you could easily run 13 of theese steppers of one mega. or basically any amount of theese steppers you want using shift registers.

Comment: @Hans Neve Sorry for my idiotic questions, but what is non-blocking code? loop+setup? What if I want to drive steppers simultaneously but with different speed and direction?

Comment: @lenyapugachev : 1) the "non-blocking" concept is something that most arduino developer will experience early in her developer career. If you already have NOT "hit" related problems, than [How and Why to avoid delay()](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/AvoidDelay) is the place where to start :-)   2) no ;  3) unfortunately I have NO experience with stepper-motors but.... my "feeling" is that you need a sort of multitasking and, as such, you definitely need to investigate point 1), that is mandatory in such a scenario :-)

Comment: ok, if I get it, yes I will avoid delay(), planning to use something like http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/AccelStepper/